# Software for rational homotopy theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory, mathematical-software

Does anybody know a software manipulating  commutative differential graded algebras, and  providing a computation of the minimal model? I tried to use the package DGAlgebras of Macaulay2, but I got several mistakes. For example the rational numbers are not allowed as ground ring, and the differential on a generator of a free CDGA is not allowed to be zero. Thanks

Comment: Did you ask Yves Felix or Pascal?
I have heard rumors of a probably like this written in C. 

Don


Answer (score 8):

SageMath has a package for cdga's written by Miguel Marco and John Palmieri, with none of the restrictions mentioned: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/algebras/sage/algebras/commutative_dga.html.

It includes a method to produce the minimal model of a cdga up to a prescribed finite degree.

Comment: To give credit where it's due, Miguel wrote the minimal model parts, not me.