# Homology software

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, big-list, mathematical-software, computational-topology

What software is there to efficiently compute homology?

Specifically:

1. What software can take a simplicial complex (provided by a file listing maximal simplices, for example) and quickly compute its homology? I am interested in which coefficients it allows ($\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{F}_q, \mathbb{Z}$).
2. What software can take a point cloud, distance matrix, graph and compute its persistent homology? An additional feature relevant for this question is which kinds of filtrations it can compute (Vietoris-Rips, Delaunay, Alpha).

I am interested in whether the software is ready to use (e.g. binary tools, Python/Julia library) or a C++ library that I first need to write a tool out of. I am also interested in the quality of the documentation.

My motivation for asking (1) is that there is a lot of software but if I simply want to compute homology of some big complex with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and I want it to be highly optimized, I don't know what to use. I include (2) because I will have to deal with it and because it will likely come up anyway.

My question is similar to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57166/computational-software-in-algebraic-topology); mine has a slightly different focus but mainly the other one is ten years old, so there might be new developments.

Here is a list of software I am aware of, but I am happy about precise information:

1. [CHomP](http://chomp.rutgers.edu/) based at Rutgers, last change 2017, no documentation. C++ library and binary tools. The library seems flexible but the tools seem to only compute rational homology.
2. [LinBox](https://linalg.org/), last change 2019, no documentation on homology computations. C++ library with GAP frontend). Computes homology with integral coefficients.
3. [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/homology/index.html) can compute homology with integral and field coefficients and has good documentation.
4. [JavaPlex](http://appliedtopology.github.io/javaplex/) (and its predecessor jPlex) based at Stanford, last change 2018, tutorial. Java library with Matlab bindings. Computes homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$. Computes persistent homology of filtered complexes and produces these from (at least) point clouds.
5. [Dionysus 2](https://github.com/mrzv/dionysus) by Dmitriy Morozov in Berkley, last change 2021, tutorial. C++ library with Python bindings. Unclear what coefficients it uses ($\mathbb{F}_2$?). Computes persistent homology of filtered complexes and produces these from (at least) point clouds.
6. [Ripser](https://github.com/Ripser/ripser) by Ulrich Bauer in Munich, last change 2021, Readme. C++ binary. Can use coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$. Computes persistence barcodes of Vietors-Rips filtrations obtained from distance matrices or point clouds.
7. [DIPHA](https://github.com/DIPHA/dipha) by Jan Reininghaus, Ulrich Bauer, Michael Kerber, last change 2017. C++ library with binary tools and Matlab bindings. Coefficients unclear. Computes persistence of Vietoris-Rips (?) filtrations from various input data.
8. [GUDHI](http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr/) developed at INRIA Sophia Antipolis and INRIA Saclay, latest change 2021, extensive examples. C++ library with Python bindings. Can compute (at least) with coefficients in a finite field. Can produce various kinds of complexes (Rips, Čech, Alpha) and computer their persistent homology.
9. [Eirene](https://github.com/Eetion/Eirene.jl), last change 2021, tutorial. Julia library. Coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Computes persistence of Vietoris-Rips complexes from point clouds aand distance matrices.

Comment: I think this should be a CW question,  since there is no one right answer.

Answer (score 4):

The [homalg_project](https://github.com/homalg-project/homalg_project/) at GitHub could be worth evaluating.

Appears to be actively maintained, updates range from days to several months ago.

Packages are documented (HTML and PDF formats).

Answer (score 2):

[Perseus](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/nanda/perseus/) (already mentioned in the older question linked to) computes persistent homology.

Answer (score 2):

The package [SimplicialComplexes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/SimplicialComplexes/html/index.html) for [Macaulay2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/) can be used to compute reduced homology of simplicial complexes over your favorite field or over $\mathbb{Z}$. Here's an example session using Reisner's triangulation of the real projective plane to show that homology may depend on the coefficients chosen.

```
needsPackage "SimplicialComplexes";

S =  ZZ[a..f];

-- Reisner's example given by its facets
C = simplicialComplex {a*b*c, a*b*d, a*c*e, a*d*f, a*e*f, b*c*f, b*d*e, b*e*f, c*d*e, c*d*f};

prune homology C -- homology over ZZ
prune homology (C, ZZ/2) -- homology over ZZ/2
prune homology (C, ZZ/3) -- homology over ZZ/3
```

Comment: Macaulay2 also allows computation of homology over polynomial rings, which is sometimes quite useful.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole, that's a good point! Indeed Macaulay2 allows computation of homology of any chain complex. The homology method in the SimplicialComplexes package just creates the simplicial chain complex and then calls the more general homology method. In this sense it may not be as optimized for simplicial complexes as other software more dedicated to the task.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning CHomP (1. on the list above) Shaun Harker just created a [branch](https://github.com/shaunharker/CHomP/tree/lite) with tools to compute with $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_3$ coefficients (and it's easy to extrapolate these to arbitrary coefficients). He also pointed out the library [pyCHomP](https://github.com/shaunharker/pyCHomP) with Python bindings which, however, only does $\mathbb{F}_2$-coefficients at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all of the latest capabilities of the software packages, but I try to keep an alphabetical list of software packages for computing persistent homology at [https://www.math.colostate.edu/~adams/advising/appliedTopologySoftware/](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eadams/advising/appliedTopologySoftware/).
If you know of software packages to add to this list, please pass them along!

Answer (score 1):

`giotto-ph` is another alternative for persistent homology. Quote from the documentation: *It consists of an improved reimplementation of Morozov and Nigmetov's "lock-free Ripser" and in addition makes use of a parallel implementation of the apparent pairs optimization used in Ripser v1.2.*

- Software is ready to use
- [Documentation](https://giotto-ai.github.io/giotto-ph/build/html/index.html) exists